# Why is my picture element overflowing its parent div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When attempting to use `<picture>` tag instead of `<img>` it's breaking out of the div. When I use only an `img` tag and set the class to `.img-fluid` works as expected. I thought a picture tag behaved like a div - what am I missing here?

I'm using Bootstrap 5.0

**Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div clas="container">
  <div clas="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <picture class="attachment-large img img-fluid size-large wp-post-image">
        <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/650 650w, https://via.placeholder.com/300 300w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">
        <img width="650" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Monovision LASIK" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/650 650w, https://via.placeholder.com/300 300w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

it's overflowing (orange) the containing div (blue)
[image]

Note: I don't have control of the actual picture tag markup (wordpress generated)

The `.img-fluid` class sets the `max-width: 100%;` so what's going on?

Comment: what is your expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

*Images* are set to 100% width with `img-fluid`. It doesn't apply to any element, but it works if you put it on the image.

```css
.col-4 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div clas="container">
  <div clas="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <picture class="attachment-large img size-large wp-post-image">
        <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/650 650w, https://via.placeholder.com/300 300w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">
        <img width="650" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Monovision LASIK" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/650 650w, https://via.placeholder.com/300 300w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px"
        class="img-fluid">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```